JS not opening a button as intended
I'm working on a header section in HTML and decided to learn JavaScript in this project. I'm also using TailwindCSS, with a few specifics I included in a different .css file.
I got the JS code from w3schools and adapted it to fit my current setup.
I don't really understand why the menu isnt opening when I click the button.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alt.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #171614;">

<script>
function menudd() {
    document.getElementById(menu-main).classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.menub')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("ddcontent");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>


    <div class="flex bg-prim py-1">
        <button onclick="menudd()" class="menub p-2 ml-2"><img src="./content/logowhite.png" width="50" height="50"></button>
        <div id="menu-main" class="ddcontent absolute bg-sec-orange mx-5 min-w-40 z-1">
            <ul>
                <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">a</li>
                <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">b</li>
                <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">c</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="relative hidden lg:flex items-center ml-auto pr-6">
            <nav class="text-sm leading-6 font-semibold text-bone">
                <ul class="ddcontent flex space-x-8">
                    <li><a class="bg-sec-orange rounded-full p-3 hover:cursor-pointer nav-button">Artists</a></li>
                    <li><a class="bg-sec-orange rounded-full p-3 hover:cursor-pointer nav-button">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>

And here's alt.css
.bg-prim {
    background-color: #7a1d00;
}

.bg-sec-orange {
    background-color: #ba3f1d;
}

.bg-sec-grey {
    background-color: #545f71;
}

.text-bone {
    color: #ece2d0;
}

.nav-button:hover {background-color: #7A1D00; transition: background-color 100ms ease-in-out;}

#menu-main {
    display: none;
}

.show {display: block;}

I tried many different things, such as playing around with Tailwind and even entering my own lines of CSS, however I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to get this working as intended.

do you get an error on document.getElementById(menu-main)....etc ? You should

You are importing id in wrong way, use double or single quotes like ("menu-main")

Your code has a few issues. do you want a simplified and better way for doing this or for some reason you want your own code to be corrected? I'll answer accordingly.

Your code does not work because #main-menu has higher specificity than .show as id selectors are more specific than class selectors. See W3 School-CSS Specificity
What you need to do is use a selector with more specificity to override the display:none property of #menu-main. Simply use #menu-main.show instead of .show
Also, in the code- if (!event.target.matches('.menub'))  you are matching for .menub but since your button has image child, clicking on the image will not open the menu. Use .menub, .menub * there. This will select the button and everything inside the button.
Lastly, you missed quotes in document.getElementById()


.bg-prim {
  background-color: #7a1d00;
}

.bg-sec-orange {
  background-color: #ba3f1d;
}

.bg-sec-grey {
  background-color: #545f71;
}

.text-bone {
  color: #ece2d0;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  background-color: #7A1D00;
  transition: background-color 100ms ease-in-out;
}

#menu-main {
  display: none;
}

#menu-main.show {
  display: block;
}
<body style="background-color: #171614;">
  <div class="flex bg-prim py-1">
    <button onclick="menudd()" class="menub p-2 ml-2"><img src="./content/logowhite.png" width="50" height="50"></button>
    <div id="menu-main" class="ddcontent absolute bg-sec-orange mx-5 min-w-40 z-1">
      <ul>
        <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">a</li>
        <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">b</li>
        <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">c</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="relative hidden lg:flex items-center ml-auto pr-6">
      <nav class="text-sm leading-6 font-semibold text-bone">
        <ul class="ddcontent flex space-x-8">
          <li><a class="bg-sec-orange rounded-full p-3 hover:cursor-pointer nav-button">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a class="bg-sec-orange rounded-full p-3 hover:cursor-pointer nav-button">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function menudd() {
      document.getElementById("menu-main").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {

      if (!event.target.matches('.menub, .menub *')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("ddcontent");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>




I just imported your CSS values in HTML file inside style tag. Later you can use it in a separate file as well.
In order to be understandable, I am leaving the whole code as i explained in COMMENTS.
Important rules you should know: CSS Specifisity, !important, Id Selector
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="alt.css">
<style>
    .bg-prim {
        background-color: #7a1d00;
    }
    
    .bg-sec-orange {
        background-color: #ba3f1d;
    }
    
    .bg-sec-grey {
        background-color: #545f71;
    }
    
    .text-bone {
        color: #ece2d0;
    }
    
    .nav-button:hover {background-color: #7A1D00; transition: background-color 100ms ease-in-out;}
    
    #menu-main {
        display: none; /* YOU ARE GIVING VALUE FOR ID SELECTOR WHICH OVERRIDES VALUES OF CLASS, EVEN IF THEY ARE ADDED LATER(IN YOUR CASE 'show')*/
    }
    
    .show {display: block !important;} /* BUT ONLY WAY YOU CAN USE '!important' TO OVERRIDE ANY PREVIOUS  STYLES*/
    
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #171614;">
 <script>
    function menudd() {
        document.getElementById('menu-main').classList.toggle("show");
        //PAY ATTENTION WHEN YOU SELECT. THEY SHOULD BE SELECTED INSIDE QUOTATION MARKS "" OR ''.
    }
    
    // window.onclick = function(event) {
    //     if (!event.target.matches('.menub')) {
    //         var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("ddcontent");
    //         var i;
    //         for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    //             var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    //             if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    //                 openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    //             }
    //         }
    //     }
    // }            WE DO NOT NEED TO CREATE THIS
</script>


<div class="flex bg-prim py-1">
    <button onclick="menudd()" class="menub p-2 ml-2"><img src="./content/logowhite.png" width="50" height="50"></button>
    <div id="menu-main" class="ddcontent absolute bg-sec-orange mx-5 min-w-40 z-1">
        <ul>
            <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">a</li>
            <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">b</li>
            <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">c</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="relative hidden lg:flex items-center ml-auto pr-6">
        <nav class="text-sm leading-6 font-semibold text-bone">
            <ul class="ddcontent flex space-x-8">
                <li><a class="bg-sec-orange rounded-full p-3 hover:cursor-pointer nav-button">Artists</a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-sec-orange rounded-full p-3 hover:cursor-pointer nav-button">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>    
</div>


**Wrong**
document.getElementById(menu-main).classList.toggle("show");

**Right**
document.getElementById('menu-main').classList.toggle("show");
// menu-main must be in double quotes "menu-main"


I pasted your code in one html file and i noticed you missed quotes in function
document.getElementById("menu-main").classList.toggle("show");
other thing i change your code take your javascript end of the page and remove this onclik event it works well. When you click button its fire menudd function its add show class and window click event take it back. So it works but you can't see.
<div class="flex bg-prim py-1">
    <button onclick="javascript:menudd()" class="menub p-2 ml-2"><img src="./content/logowhite.png" width="50" height="50"></button>
    <div id="menu-main" class="ddcontent absolute bg-sec-orange mx-5 min-w-40 z-1">
        <ul>
            <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">a</li>
            <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">b</li>
            <li class="px-12 py-2 block text-center nav-button cursor-pointer">c</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="relative hidden lg:flex items-center ml-auto pr-6">
        <nav class="text-sm leading-6 font-semibold text-bone">
            <ul class="ddcontent flex space-x-8">
                <li><a class="bg-sec-orange rounded-full p-3 hover:cursor-pointer nav-button">Artists</a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-sec-orange rounded-full p-3 hover:cursor-pointer nav-button">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>    
</div>

<script>
    function menudd() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("menu-main");
        elem.classList.toggle("show");
    }
</script>

